# Dataframe - не могу достать колонку Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Фреймворк - JUpiter

Загрузил исторические данные с помощью модуля Quandl и положил их в DataFrame:
[image: Загруженные данные]

Но при попытке достать столбец 'Data', получаю ошибку (все остальные столбцы достает без проблем):

Код:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "fSMkfe4HmxcKvQ97yDkQ"
data = quandl.get('WIKI/FB', start_date = '2012-06-01', end_date = '2016-08-01')

#quandl_data = data[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]

data['Date']
```

Ошибка:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-1833f9ed79d6> in <module>
      6 #quandl_data = data[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]
      7 
----> 8 data['Date']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Date'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имя столбца(ов) находится ниже остальных столбцов - это значит, что это именованный **индекс**.

К индексу можно обратиться так:

```
data.index
```

или можно превратить его в обычный столбец и после этого обращаться к нему как к обычному столбцу:

```
data = data.reset_index()
data["Date"]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает